# "textarea" multilines PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I am using php and html codes in the same file for a contact form.

When I write multiple lines in a html form (textarea):

```
(name="TBody" cols="100" rows="10" class="largertextarea" required="required" placeholder="Leave A Message Here"),
```

the php received the information and put all of them in the same line :

```
$body = $_POST["TBody"];
$msgbody = "- Message is about:" . "<br>" . $body;
```

For example :

```
Hi,
Hope all are fine.
Bye.
```

What I receive in email is like this :

```
Hi, Hope all are fine. Bye.
```

So, how can I put them in multiple lines?

Comment: ever heard of `<BR>` ?

Comment: you can always use web editor like [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/), it will have all your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you catch your $_Post['textarename']

Use
    $message=nl2br($_POST["TBody"];);

Then   that will save your `<br>` tags from textarea

Comment: Yes, I wrote this $body = nl2br($_POST['TBody']);

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example that could give you the basic idea of how it's done:

```
  If(isset($_POST['submit']){
$msg= nl2br($_POST['text']);
}
```

Now line breaks are added where they should be, if you're displaying this on html however you don't have to use the nl2br function, but use the CSS property:

```
div{
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```